# Error with reactjs App.test.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get this error while trying to run npm.test for the App.test.js that you get when installing reactjs. Any thoughts on how to solve this? I've added some extra code etc now.

```
> client@0.1.0 test /Users/filipmyllari/Documents/1DV430/fm222hp- 
project/client
react-scripts test --env=jsdom

>2018-05-29 16:26 node[535] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: 
register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-22)
2018-05-29 16:26 node[535] (FSEvents.framework) FSEventStreamStart: 
register_with_server: ERROR: f2d_register_rpc() => (null) (-22)
events.js:182
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

>Error: Error watching file for changes: EMFILE
at _errnoException (util.js:1019:11)
at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1360:9)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Here is the package.json file

```
{
 "name": "client",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
 "add": "^2.0.6",
 "babel-jest": "^23.0.1",
 "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
 "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
 "firebase": "^4.13.1",
 "jest": "^23.0.1",
 "lodash": "^4.17.5",
 "react": "^16.3.1",
 "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
 "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
 "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
 "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.0",
 "yarn": "^1.7.0"
 },
 "scripts": {
 "start": "react-scripts start",
 "build": "react-scripts build",
 "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
 "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
 "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2"
}
}
```

The code comes below here (App.test.js)

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div)
})

describe('Addition', () => {
  it('knows that 2 and 2 make 4', () => {
    expect(2 + 2).toBe(4);
  });
});
```

Comment: EMFILE means “too many open files” – my guess is that you're accidentally watching the node_modules directory for file changes

Comment: @PatrickHund How do I fix that then?

Comment: It's hard to say when all you share is the error message. Is this based on create-react-app, or did you do your own setup? Can you edit your question to include webpack config, package.json, etc.?

Comment: @PatrickHund Added more now

Comment: OK, so it seems you are using create-react-app. I've tried running your test on my own machine with a freshly created react app, runs without errors. Sorry, I'm afraid I can't help you fix that. I've uprooted the question, hopefully someone else can.

Comment: Alright thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem when facing testing with Jest.

I would suggest you installing `watchman` as proposed in [Jest issue 1767](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1767).

```
brew install watchman
```

After installing any test should go without a problem, it has resolved such problems on my and some of my work colleagues computers so I believe it can be also worth trying for you.

---

Furthermore some latest response on issue suggest updating Jest to omit the error:

> Ultimately, updating to Jest 23.1.0 resolved the issue.
>   [(releaf)](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1767#issuecomment-395881227)

Comment: I can second that, I had the same issue and as Xarvalus describes, having watchman installed makes it go away.